# Taking screenshot in testng

Tags: java, testng

```
File source;    
source = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String dest=System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/errorscreenshot/" + screenshotname + ".png";
File destination=new File(dest);
FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me why is that I am seeing Nullpointer exception when Testcase gets failed.

Comment: did you ceck the source and destination what return ?

Comment: I have added print line to see what source is printing. But Control not even  taking to that line

Comment: I mean Null Pointer Exception it is throwing while calling getScreenshotAs method()

Comment: Do I need to Get the driver.  I mean something like (driver= .getdriver())

Comment: Please define the question inside the topic, not as a comment.
Follow the guidelines for creating a topic. :)